# Sliding Window/Buffer in Reactive Framework

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

I want to create a variable length window/buffer of input events that lengthens as it receives additional events.

This is to implement "search as you type" functionality. I want to capture the click, but in order not to stress the server, I want to make the service call judiciously.

The logic I have in mind is to buffer the key strokes, starting from the first key down, until a key up  + 1 second delay. So if the user is still typing (ie hitting the keyboard at a frequency of < 1 sec), we will not be calling the backside services.  However once they stopped typing for 1 second, the call is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Throttle feature from Rx.

To accomplish what you want in C# and Javascript (the question being tagged with c# and rxjs even if javascript is certainly what you need) :

In [Rxjs](http://rxjs.codeplex.com/), you'll find a great tutorial in [here](http://cburgdorf.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/cleaning-up-with-the-help-of-rxjs/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myInput')
        .toObservable("keyup")
        .Select(function(){ return $('#myInput').val(); })
        .Throttle(500)
        .Subscribe(function(text){ console.log("fire up ajax call"); });
});
```

In [Rx.Net](http://rx.codeplex.com/), you'll find an interesting sample in [here](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30) :

```
SearchTextChangedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(this.textBox, "TextChanged");
_currentSubscription = SearchTextChangedObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5)).ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(e => this.ListItems.Add(this.textBox.Text));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, thank you!!! :D I was thinking of various ways to implement this just in case there's no out of the box way, so you saved me a bunch.